# Dynamic external identity providers configuration in AspNet Identity

Tags: asp.net-identity, identityserver4, openid-connect, sustainsys-saml2

What I have IdentityServer4 project which uses ASP.NET Identity for identity management. Authentication configured to use external identity providers:

- AddOpenIdConnect - for openid connect compatible providers,
- AddSaml2 - for saml compatible ones (I am using Sustainsys.Saml2 library, https://github.com/Sustainsys/Saml2)

I am trying to accomplish dynamic configuration of external identity providers through UI.
I found one mentioning of similar problem on github thread (https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/2366).

Did anyone try to accomplish something similar, are there any pitfalls? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: not sure if you managed to solve this issue by now but I'm facing the same challenge using version 5 of Identity Server: they provide dynamic providers and they have some documentation in [here](https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v5/ui/login/dynamicproviders/).